# How To: Update table with new data but exclude the last second and include it in the next update

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am using azure data explorer and I have a table in which my data is ingested ("A"). Now I want to run a analysis on that data and safe it in another table. ("B")

I am using an update function in which the analysis is done ("update_function") and have created a table "B" in which the analysis results should be stored.

These are the policy settings: `

```
.alter table B policy update
@'[{"IsEnabled": true, "Source": "A", "Query": "Update_function()", "IsTransactional": false, "PropagateIngestionProperties": false}]'
```

```
.alter table B policy ingestionbatching @'{  "MaximumBatchingTimeSpan": "00:10:00",  "MaximumNumberOfItems": 100000, "MaximumRawDataSizeMB": 1024}'
```

So the function is run every 10 minutes, does the analysis on the data which as been ingested in A since the last Update of B and stores the results in B.

Everything works fine as far. 
The problem is: 
**My frequeny of data is around 5 per second. 
In the analysis I use a `summarize xxx by bin(timestamp,1s)` so I have a result for every second. Because the update is sometimes in the middle of a second I get double results for that second in table B.**

For example.

1. Date 02:00:00.967
2. Date 02:00:01.234
3. Date 02:00:01.456
4. Date 02:00:01.754
5. Date 02:00:01.897
6. Date 02:00:02.190

If the update funtion runs before 5. than I will have in B a row with Date 02.00.01 summarizing 2.,3. and 4. and the next run of the update function will add an row summarizing 5.

**I want the update function to only use the data which as been newly ingested into table A AND where the timestamp is not the last second.**

So in the example it would take 1. but leave 2.,3. and 4. for the next function run.

**So that in the next update this data can be included then and the second can be analysed as one.**

It´s not possible to just fuse the data later in B as it is importan that the analysis runs on all the data of 1 second.

I hope someone can help me out and that there is a way how to do it.

Greetings,
Katharina

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Azure Data Explorer today, other than to build your own orchestration which periodically queries the table (with some introduced latency, to make sure it's not querying the last second), and uses set-or-append commands to store the aggregated data in the target table. There's a new feature we are working on, called materialized views, which will support this scenario, but it's not publicly available yet. I suggest checking back in a couple of months.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer ! How  do  I do the orchestration? Is there  some documentation for this? Grettings, Katharina

Comment: Take a look at this section in the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/#orchestration-tools. Logic Apps is one possible candidate. Assuming you query by a Timestamp column in your data, invoke a .set-or-append command every interval (interval can be few minutes) to query the data since last iteration, aggregate it and append to target table. Every execution needs to persist the last Timestamp it processed and next iteration should query from that point.

Comment: I am trying to do it with Microsoft Flow now. I have managed to get the last timestamp that was processed with :


.set-or-append B<|
let lastTimestamp=toscalar(B| summarize max(timestamp));
let d= A|where trackerType has "x" and timestamp  >todatetime(lastTimestamp)

Now what I still don´t know is how to sed the 1 second full condition. 


timestamp <=last full second. with timestamp<=ago(1s) I would not receive the wanted result. Do you have an idea for this? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Found a way but I don´t think it is very elegant: 
let firstTimestamp=toscalar(A|where timestamp>todatetime(lastTimestamp)|summarize by bin(timestamp,1s)|summarize max(timestamp));

Comment: I'll try to demonstrate briefly - assume you define a forced latency of 20m (data cannot be more than 20m "late"). Assume table T includes the last timestamp you processed. Init by: `.set-or-replace T <| print Timestamp=now()`. In each iteration run: `.set-or-append Target <| let fromTime = toscalar(T | limit 1); Source | where Timestamp between ((fromTime+1tick) .. ago(20m)) | summarize xxx by bin(Timestamp, 1s)`. And then - `.set-or-replace T <| print ago(20m)` (the  `ago(20m)` should be computed once between both commands, so you need to compute in the flow once and add to the commands).

Comment: Hey, 
I don´t think I completely understood your answer. 
First I initiate a table T in which i store the current timestamp. Then I set up the power automate flow which I run every 10 minutes (thats the time intervall I want). 
In this flow I include a query in which I do my logic based on the timestamp in T and when I finish I set T again. But why set T to print ago(10m)? I would believe I need to set it it to now().

Comment: Doing the logic like this :
 .set-or-append Target <| let fromTime = toscalar(T | limit 1); Source | where Timestamp >=((fromTime+1tick)  | summarize xxx by bin(Timestamp, 1s). And then - .set-or-replace T <| print Timestamp=now()